# Cloud function to Delete a DB in Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to delete a db in cloud sql (postgres) using cloud function,

```
dbDeleteResp, err := sqladminService.Databases.Delete(projectName, instanceName, dbName).Context(ctx).Do()
```

and getting following exception

```
db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqlagent ERROR: must be owner of database XXXX
```

Is it possible to grant a permission to cloudsqlagent user to delete a database in cloud SQL ?

Comment: The role would be: `roles/cloudsql.admin`; see [predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles).

Comment: Can you try using the REST API mentioned here to see if you get the same error ? (pay attention to the scopes) https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/databases/delete

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Cloud SQL Admin API documentation for [`databases.delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/databases/delete), you'll see it requires the IAM role `sqlservice.admin`. Make sure that the service account for this function has that role.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL is a managed service.  You, the user, do not *own* the database.  GCP retains ownership behind the scenes.

In order to do owner-level activity, such as deleting a database, you need to go through proper GCP APIs.

Per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-databases), you can make a REST API call from your Cloud Function to accomplish this:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-id/instances/instance-id/databases/database-name
```

Make sure your Cloud Function service account has the appropriate Cloud SQL permissions!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the context of your question.  That `sqlAdminService` _is_ using the underlying GCP APIs.

Comment: To troubleshoot this -- do you get the same error when you try deleting the database using `gcloud sql databases delete [DB NAME] --instance [INSTANCE NAME]` with your gcloud session authenticated with a user account that has `cloudsql.admin` role?

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you that `gcloud` is using the service account you think it is?

Confirm when you run `gcloud info` that the project you THINK it's using is the right project, and then when you ran `gcloud auth login` and that the user you're logging in with has sufficient permissions.

The alternative is to setup `gcloud` with a service account, which there's a good how-to found here: https://medium.com/@pnatraj/how-to-run-gcloud-command-line-using-a-service-account-f39043d515b9

As others said in their comments, the role/permission you need is `roles/cloudsql.admin`.